# Eclipse warning: Cannot be null?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, warnings, binary-search-tree

I'm getting what I think is a spurious warning from Eclipse on the following code, used to count the number of times a given element appears in a binary tree:

```
public int count(E item)
{
    int count = 0;
    Node crnt = root;
    //First seek the item in the tree
    while (crnt != null)
    {
        int compare = crnt.data.compareTo(item);
        if (compare > 0)
            crnt = crnt.right;
        else if (compare < 0)
            crnt = crnt.left;
        else
        {
            //Shortcut if not allowing duplicate entries
            if (!allowDuplicates)
                return 1;
            count++;
            //Duplicates are always stored to the right
            while (crnt != null) // <--Warning appears here
            {
                crnt = crnt.right;
                if (crnt.data.compareTo(item) == 0)
                    count++;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

<sup>(I could show you the Node class, but it's nothing surprising.  Just an `E for the data and two Node pointers for left and right children.)</sup>

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Eclipse?  Because it seems like it's perfectly possible, and in fact *expected* for `crnt` to be possibly null in this case, once it runs out of right children.  Granted it won't be null the *first* time it hits this loop, but usually the IDE is smart enough to realize when the value of the variable changes within the loop.  Not this time, however.  Eclipse is suggesting I put a `@SuppressWarnings("null")` on this, or I could go into the settings and turn off this warning altogether, but I don't think it should be necessary, and I hate suppressing or ignoring warnings where they might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crnt` will still be different from `null` because it is in the `else` clause of the if-elseif-else statement that **might** change `crnt`. Its value will never have changed when it hits the second `while` statement.

It's doing exactly as it should: telling you that the value of `crnt` will never be null when that code hits and that the additional check in the `while` unnecessary is.

Per avice by David Wallace: there is no possibility that the inner loop will be `null` because the `crnt` object is already accessed prior to that by the line `int compare = crnt.data.compareTo(item);`, essentially forming a prerequisite that `crnt` must not be `null`.

Comment: Yes, but within the internal while loop, the value of `crnt` can and will change - it's the first line inside the loop.  The first while condition won't be checked again until it's done looping in the second while.

Comment: Yes, but if it changes to null, you'll get a null pointer exception when you do `crnt.data.compareTo(item)`.  So it's not going to be null AND come back to the `while` condition.  @Jeroen, if you edit your answer to mention this, I will upvote you.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ooh - good catch.  It's supposed to be checking that `crnt.right != null`.  Sure enough, without the compareTo line, the warning goes away.  That's the real answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I have edited my answer to reflect that. Feel free to do so yourself in the future, I left my desk for a bit :)

Comment: Yeah, that one was a real forehead-smacker.  I'm sure I'd have figured it out as soon as I tried running this code and getting null pointer exceptions out of it.  I'm actually impressed Eclipse was able to catch this unreachable state, though less impressed that it didn't explain how it was unreachable.  Would've never guessed `compareTo()` as the culprit...